# How to fix this code to insert all document from the excel file in my database because the last row doesn't inserted

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, stream, xlsx

Hello I have problem which is always the last row from my excel file doesn't inserted to my database
I tried to log every step but I noticed the end event fire before the data event so how to fix this problem and is there is any ideas to improve this code I am very stuck in this problem.
thank you

```
const { OurMedicine } = require('../../models/pharamacists/ourMedicine');
const XLSX = require('xlsx');
const fastcsv = require('fast-csv');

/**
 * @desc Uploads a CSV file of medicine information to the database
 * @param {Object} req - The request object
 * @param {Object} res - The response object
 * @return {Object} A response indicating success or failure, and two lists of brand names for new and existing medicines
 */
async function ourMedicine(req, res) {
  try {
    // Check if a file was uploaded
    if (!req.file) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: 'Error: No file uploaded'
      });
    }

    // Check if the file is in XLSX format
    const fileExtension = req.file.originalname.split('.').pop();
    if (fileExtension !== 'xlsx') {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: 'Error: File must be in .xlsx format'
      });
    }

    // Read the Excel file and get the first sheet
    const workbook = XLSX.readFile(req.file.path);
    const sheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0];
    const sheet = workbook.Sheets[sheetName];

    // Define the expected headers for the Excel file
    const expectedHeaders = {
      'name': 'A1',
      'age': 'B1'
    };

    // Check that the headers in the Excel file match the expected headers
    for (const [headerName, cell] of Object.entries(expectedHeaders)) {
      const sheetCell = sheet[cell];
      const trimmedHeaderName = headerName.trim();
      if (!sheetCell || typeof sheetCell.v !== 'string') {
        return res.status(400).json({
          message: `Please fill in the blank cell at ${cell} with the value ${trimmedHeaderName}`
        });
      } else if (sheetCell.v.trim().toLowerCase() !== trimmedHeaderName) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          message: `Please rename ${cell} to ${trimmedHeaderName}`
        });
      }
    }

    // Check the number of characters in each cell
    for (const cellAddress in sheet) {
      const sheetCell = sheet[cellAddress];
      if (sheetCell.v && typeof sheetCell.v === 'string' && sheetCell.v.length > 600) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          message: `Please make cell ${cellAddress} contains less than 600 characters`
        });
      }
    }

    // Convert the sheet to a CSV stream using XLSX
    const csvStream = XLSX.stream.to_csv(sheet);

    // Initialize lists of brand names for new and existing medicines
    const newMedicines = [];
    const alreadyExist = [];

    // Create an array to store the documents to be inserted
    const insertDocuments = [];

    // Parse the CSV data using fast-csv
    const parser = fastcsv.parse({ headers: true })
      .on('data', async (data) => {
        
        // Convert all keys to lowercase and trim them to match the field names in the schema
        const keys = Object.keys(data);
        
        const lowerCaseKeys = keys.map(key => key.toLowerCase().trim());
        
        const newData = {};
        for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
          newData[lowerCaseKeys[i]] = data[keys[i]];
        }
        
        // Check if a document with the same registration number already exists in the collection
        const existingDoc = await OurMedicine.findOne({ name: newData.name });
        if (existingDoc) {
          // If the document exists, add its brand name to the list of existing medicines
          alreadyExist.push({bran: existingDoc.name, rigistration_number: existingDoc.age});
        } else {
          // If the document is new, add its brand name to the list of new medicines and add it to the array of documents to be inserted
          newMedicines.push(newData.name);
          insertDocuments.push(newData);
          console.log(`${insertDocuments} +pp`)
          console.log(insertDocuments)
        }


      })
      .on('end', async () => {
        // If there is data in the CSV file, insert the documents using bulkWrite
        if (insertDocuments.length > 0) {
          const result = await OurMedicine.bulkWrite(
            insertDocuments.map(doc => ({
              insertOne: {
                document: doc
              }
            }))
          );
          console.log(`${insertDocuments} +ppp`)
          console.log(`${result.insertedCount} documents inserted into MongoDB`);
        }

        // Send a response with the two lists
        res.json({ newMedicines, alreadyExist });
      });

    // Pipe the CSV stream to the parser
    csvStream.pipe(parser);

  } catch (ex) {
    // If there is an error, send an internal server error response
    console.error(ex);
    res.status(500).json({
      error: 'Internal server error'
    });
  }
}

module.exports = {
  ourMedicine
};
```

I expect this code to receive large amount of data

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is you are waiting for the 'end' event of the CSV parser before putting the documents in the database. Try editing your code to insert documents immediately when they are processed in the 'data' event and then move the response submission logic to the 'end' event.Give it a try maybe that's the problem!